# Trying to replace a break but keep the same result in python

Tags: python, break

I am new to coding and was told that using breaks is a bad form of programming. I was wondering if anyone knew a good way to change the break without changing how the program functions? I have attached the code I am working with.[Code in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKyno.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's a lot easier to help when you post code as text, not as an image.

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with using `break`, especially in a case like this.  Whoever told you that is doing you a disservice.

Answer (score 0):

Running your code I don't see any problems. What I would change is that you can make `a` an argument for the function and return True or False, like this:

```
def isprime(a):
    c=a-1
    for i in range(2, c):
        b=a%i
        if b == 0:
            return False
    else:
        return True

isprime(4)
isprime(7)
```

In this example I replaced `break` with `return`, this will break the loop but also return whether the number is prime or not.

To clarify, there is nothing wrong with using `break` and I think it is a very usefull possibility when looping.

Comment: It's especially useful in Python because of the `else:` clause of its loops.

Comment: I never knew that was a thing, dont even really know how it works.

Comment: The `else:` block is executed if the loop runs to completion rather than being exited with `break`. It's not really needed in your version, because you return instead of breaking. You can simply put `return true` after the loop.

Comment: I wasn't going for neatness, per say, just for useability and understandability as in copying the format of the questioner